# Transition between pages in jQuery mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am working on an app which has some pages and here is the flow:

`page1 -> page2 -> page -> 3 -> page1`

Now whenever I press the back button, if I am on page 1, I have to exit the app, and if I am om other pages, I have to go back to previous page.

If it was native Android development, we have `Intents`, which we can use to transition between pages.

I am new to jQuery mobile and Phonegap, do we have anything similar to `Intents` in Phonegap/jQuery mobile? Or is there any other way I can perform the above?

Answer (score 0):

Add transition when you write the code for button

You can add this script on button click:

```
$.mobile.changePage('URL', { options } );
```

Have a look on this [link](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/)

Comment: Oh Okay! Then check the answer given by Mayu.. It will work! :)

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume your page id for the page 1 is `pageone`.

Your html would be something like this

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
</div>
```

You can get the page's id using following script

```
    if($.mobile.activePage.attr("id") == "pageone"){
     // Code to exit or logout
    }
```

Using above condition you can decide whether to exit or proceed to previous page.

Android back button will usually take you to previous page you visited. So you need to handle android back button to avoid being taken into page 3 from page 1.

Finally it would look something as below

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

// Handle the back button
function onBackKeyDown() {
    if($.mobile.activePage.attr("id") == "pageone"){
     // Code to exit or logout
    }
    else{
      history.back()
    }
}
```

I have not tested it yet. But ideally it should work for you.

Comment: i tried this, now in none of my screen back button is working.:(

Comment: this is how i tried `function onDeviceReady() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

// Handle the back button
function onBackKeyDown() {
    if($.mobile.activePage.attr("id") == "list"){
      navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else{
      history.back()
    }
}
`

Comment: can you check whether you are getting any errors in console? check DDMS for logcat

Comment: can you put a console.log to `else` block and see whether `history.back()` is being executed?

Answer (score 0):

Mayu is really close to the solution I used in my app.

```
if($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == 'pageone'){
   navigator.app.exitApp();
} else {
   navigator.app.backHistory();
}
```